# What does error in IDE Ubuntu 64 mean?

Tags: ide

Whenever I open a Salesforce project in Force.com IDE, I get this error message:
[image]

It prevents me from saving any chances to Salesforce. Here is one such error message:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Save error: Unable to perform save on all files: com.salesforce.ide.api.metadata.types.Metadata$JaxbAccessorF_fullName cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor  HandleProductPriceChange.trigger    /Warehouse/src/triggers line 1  Force.com save problem
```

I am working on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit, Force.com IDE version 26.0

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (7u9-2.3.3-0ubuntu1~12.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: I would also try replacing the Open JdK with the Sun JDK, I think I had problems with Eclipse on Ubuntu when it auto upgraded Java from to Open JDK from Sun JDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're out of the supported platform matrix with your development stack, see:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Release_Notes#Supported_Platforms

for details of supported platform.

Comment: Okay, going back to such an old version is out of debate, so I should switch to Eclipse + plugin?

Comment: Yeah I think I got Eclipse + IDE to work okay on Ubuntu. Prolly also try running the Force iDE via Wine?

Answer (score 4):

This is typically caused by using an unsupported version of the JRE. Specifically, version 7 of the JRE causes this issue so you will need to downgrade to version 6.

1. **Check your JRE version**: This can be found under the help menu -> "about eclipse platform" (or "about force.com ide") -> installation details -> configuration details. You should see the properties java.runtime.name and java.runtime.version.
2. **Change the JRE version in your eclipse.ini file**: Instructions for finding the location of your ini file for eclipse are [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). You  need to set the -vm argument like they have in the example.
3. **Restart eclipse and check that you are using the correct JRE**: Open the configuration details from step 1 and search for the -vm argument to make sure eclipse is looking for java in the place you put in your ini file.

Note: I can confirm that version 6 of the OpenJDK JRE (openjdk-7-jre) works without any issues on 64-bit ubuntu.

Comment: Well, downgrading is not very handy as I use Java for more apps than only this. I guess it would be best to run Force.com IDE in a virtualbox.

Comment: @MartinBetz You do not need to downgrade. That's why I recommended putting the JRE version in your ini file so that you don't need to change $JAVA_HOME or any PATH variable. All your other programs can continue to use openjdk-7 or whatever you have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying your question is 100% duplicate but have a look at [Unable to refresh src from server using force.com IDE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/649/unable-to-refresh-src-from-server-using-force-com-ide), similar error message.

I used to get this one sometime on Windows 7 64-bit. Mostly when I create a new project (for example I need to reference a newly created sandbox & start working in it), sometimes when project is old but I want to make a new Apex class.

While Phil might have a good idea about it being unsupported (some incompatibility fun with 32/64 bit versions of plugins?) please try if answers from the other question change anything for you.

I simply restart the IDE or "switch workspace". Sometimes restart with "run as administrator". I believe it flushes some cache/obtains access to files that were previously non-writeable... I don't know really. ["Cargo cult"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue all the time. I am the same as @eyescream I just restart the IDE and the problem is solved.

I have been able to isolate this issue but never done anything about it. The way to reproduce the problem is to create a new apex class or trigger in the IDE.

It will save the class or trigger to the server but make a change and it will not save. This only seems to be a problem if "Build Automatically" is checked in the IDE. a Manual save does not cause a problem.