# Force.com IDE error

Tags: ide

I am getting following error whenever I try to fetch meta-data. Any idea how to resolve this?
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to refresh src from server using force.com IDE](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/649/unable-to-refresh-src-from-server-using-force-com-ide) and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/what-does-error-in-ide-ubuntu-64-mean ;)

Comment: Are you connecting to a Spring 13 or Summer 13 instance? What platform/Java are you running the IDE on?

Comment: have you tried shutting down the IDE and restarting it? sometimes helps

Comment: @MikeChale Java 7

Comment: @PJC yes I also tried that but no luck